# CRITICAL DATETIME FUNCTION ISSUE FOR STOCK MARKET SAMPLE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hi I am facing one critical issue , please suggest some solution.

I have a record in my Sql table like the below:

```
Table Name (tbl_rawdata)

ID    Price     DATE

1      20     20/8/2014 

2      20     20/8/2013
```

Hence we don't have the actual data we need to create sample data and test.

ex: We need to insert 60 records as the same showed in the table but the date will be different.

```
ID    Price     DATE

1      20     20/8/2014 
1      20     21/8/2014 
1      20     22/8/2014 
-----------------------
1      20     25/8/2014
------------------------ 
1      20     26/8/2014 
1      20     27/8/2014 
1      20     28/8/2014
```

that means we need to get the next date (Excluding Saturday and Sunday's) like that we need to insert for 60 days.

In the same way we have different id values (around 100) in tbl_rawdata , we need to repeat the same for all.

Please help on this case. Thanks in advance and waiting for your response

Comment: Please mention your DBMS.

Comment: @DIMIT :sql server 2008 r2

Comment: @patrick: didn't understand not shouting sir

Comment: @patrick:sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can remove the dayName from the results if not desired:

```
DECLARE @FirstDate DATETIME
-- You can change @year to any year you desire
SELECT @FirstDate = '20140820'
-- Creating Query to Prepare Year Data
;WITH cte AS (
   SELECT 1 AS ID,
   @FirstDate AS FromDate,
   DATENAME(dw, @FirstDate) AS Dayname
UNION ALL
    SELECT CASE WHEN DayName NOT IN ('Saturday','Sunday') THEN cte.ID + 1
                ELSE cte.ID END AS ID,
    DATEADD(d, 1 ,cte.FromDate),
    DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(d, 1 ,cte.FromDate)) AS Dayname
FROM cte
WHERE ID < 60
)
SELECT ID, 20 AS Price, FromDate AS Date, Dayname
FROM CTE
WHERE DayName NOT IN ('Saturday','Sunday')
```

Comment: it seems good, but need some clarification on this. For example in the stock market not only satur day's and sundays some times we will have public holidays also, if we need to ignore those means can we do anything for that

Comment: You are going to need some sort of date table then,that  allows you to define days as weekends, holidays, or anything else you may want to exclude.  And it would have been helpful if you had included this requirement in your original post.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew. @Chaitanya Phani, there are two places where the days to exclude are set, both with this condition: `DayName NOT IN ('Saturday','Sunday')`. You can replace this with some other condition that specifies the days you want to exclude, like `FromDate NOT IN (SELECT date FROM tbl_excludedDates)`

Comment: @user16484: Perfect solution  and sorry for missing this query into the question

Comment: @Andrew: i am new to this forum let  me learn the way of asking the question. thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select id, price,dateadd(day,number,date) from tbl_rawdata as t1, 
master..spt_values as t2 
where type='p' and number<60 and datename(weekday,dateadd(day,number,date)) not in
('saturday','sunday')
```

Comment: sorry sir, it is giving + 7 days data which is not sufficent. Query is small but will be useful for some other scenario.

Comment: Instead of week parameter you need to use day. I edited the code, Try it

Comment: It's giving saturday and sunday also,@16484 solution is good , but based on that can we improvize something like saturday and sunday we know these are the holidays for the stock market, but can we give some static day's also like 29-08-2014 is public holiday, can we ignore that day also from the query

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
DECLARE @Table1 AS TABLE (ID int, Price int, [Date] smalldatetime) 
DECLARE @Table2 AS TABLE (ID int, Price int, [Date] smalldatetime)
INSERT INTO @Table1(ID, Price, [Date]) 
SELECT 1, 20, '2014-08-20 00:00:00.000' UNION SELECT 2, 20, '2013-08-20 00:00:00.000'

DECLARE @DateRange int = 0

WHILE @DateRange < 60
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @Table2
SELECT ID, Price, [Date] + @DateRange
FROM @Table1
SET @DateRange = @DateRange+1
END
DELETE @Table2 WHERE DATEPART(DW,[Date]) in (7,1)

SELECT *
FROM @Table2
```